# add line to nls fit and plot

Tags: r, plot, nls

I am having problems adding a line to one scatter plot. My data is fit to an exponential model.  I used `nls` to get coefficients:

```
fit <- nls(volumen ~ bo+ exp(b1*dap), data= df, start = list(bo=0, b1=55))
```

Later I used `plot` and `lines` commands to visualize the `fit` to my data:

```
plot(dap,volumen)
lines(dap,predict(fit,data.frame(x=dap)))
```

My Big problem is that I visualize a linear line that does not fit with my exponential points.

Could my model statement have errors?

Please, any comments I would appreciate.

Comment: You may be giving a different set of values to the predict function. (`dap` may not be `df$dap`.) And you have not offered the data in `df`. I don't see how you expect the worldwide SO audience to offer much in the way of specific advice.

Comment: Maybe you just have a bad fit. Hard to say without more information from you.

Comment: It would be easier to help you with a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)